# Single slit diffraction from Feynman's rotating amplitudes ("Little Arrows")

Tags: optics, path-integral, simulations, quantum-optics, diffraction

In Feynman's [NZ lectures](http://www.feynman.com/science/qed-lectures-in-new-zealand/) (and consequent book) “QED – The Strange Theory of Light and Matter”, he gives a model for optics.

He describes a probability amplitude for a photon to be detected after being emitted from a source. The amplitude is a complex number, whose angle rotates at a constant rate (depending on the photon frequency), and whose modulus is proportional to $1/l$, where $l$ is the path length. The total amplitude is the sum of amplitudes from different paths. The probability is the total amplitude's square-length. This is a simplified model for the Path Integral.

I have build a Mathematica simulation for this method. I tried to simulate a single-slit experiment: a source (at the origin), a slit (at x-position $d$, y-positions $-yrange \to yrange$), and a detector at varying positions $(1,h)$. For each detector, I run over different paths (like the blue and yellow paths below). Each path is two straight-lines: origin to some middle point $(d,y)$, and from the slit to the detector. I sum over all paths with $y$ as a parameter. The photon wavenumber is $k$. The probability is not normalized in this method.

[image: Experiment diagram]

[image: Code&Plot]
For $k=20$:

[image: Larger k plot]

**As you can see, I do not get a $Sinc^2$**. What am I missing?

Comment: You only need to calculate this from the two edges of the slit to anywhere on the detection screen. I did something similar in my paper “Single Edge Certainty” at Billalsept.com

Comment: Wouldn't that be a double-slit equivalent?

Comment: no, a single slit has two edges and a double slit has four edges.

Comment: @BillAlsept I'm confused. The method that Feynman gives includes a sum over all paths. Are you saying that this is the wrong calculation, or just that you have a simpler equivalent?

Comment: Feynman is correct I’m just saying for a slit calculation you only need it from the edges to the detection screen.

Comment: Try increasing the path distance to the screen, your diagram is not to scale?  Try slit    0.4mm, source 10 cm, screen 10m, wavelength 600nm.....  Maybe generate 100 paths to each point on the screen and maybe calculate the pattern over say 1m in 0.1mm increments at the screen....

Comment: I tried larger distances and larger wavenumbers. That seems to work. thanks

Comment: You can answer your own question below ... it would be nice to see the graph! I'll upvote it.

Comment: @BillAlsept -see my comment below about classical math vs Feynman math.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the slit was too close to the source and to the screen. I have also made the wavenumber higher.

When both distances are $50$, and $k=1,000$:

[image: single slit]

For two slits (source to slits $=500$, slits to screen $=500$, $k=500$, slit-width $=0.2$, slit distance $=1$):

[image: double slit]

Comment: Here is a link to a nice setup that gets good results and it shows all the dimensions they used to get the practical results.  https://dash.harvard.edu/bitstream/handle/1/27413728/single_photon_paper.pdf?sequence=4

Comment: Your double slit result is very good but the peaks are very narrow and I'm not sure if any practical/simple setup could ever show them this narrow. In practice laser light sources are wide and the light has a gaussian distribution and these practicalities force experimenters to use longer distances to see the results.

Comment: It is interesting that the classical (interference) math gives a very similar result to the Feynman approach.  In fact any theory that assumes some kind of cancellation (which can violate energy conservation) will assume that the waves need to be 1/2 wavelength offset and many geometric approaches can be proposed ... but may/will violate energy conservation.

Comment: In general the Feynman approach says every photon finds its own path ..... the net of all the math shows that the paths that are harmonic (i.e. path length is an integer  multiple of wavelength) are the paths that the photons follow. An excited electron in an atom is already giving off forces and interacting with the EM field (virtual photons) before the real photon is even released ... this may be how a photon predetermines its path.

Comment: The classical interference approach is so popular, since Younge in 1801, and the math is easier to explain so the classical theory lives on. But it does nothing to help explain the single photon experiments or how to resolve conservation of energy.  In Feymans time they never had access to single photon detectors, it was the Japanese in the 1950s that did the experiment.

Comment: @PhysicsDave An oscillating photon Does not violate energy conservation. Just like any system that oscillates, it goes through cycles of positive and negative. Did you read my derivation at billalsept.com

Comment: @PhysicsDave every photon does follow a unique path but are not selective to only harmonic paths. Photons randomly follow every path and Impact every point along the pattern both positive and negative.