# How one explains the formation of this type of fringe pattern of double slit experiement with wavelength comparable to width?

Tags: optics, waves, interference, diffraction

How can the fringe pattern by two slits which are satisfying the "criteria of wavelength being comparable to slith widths" , show the pattern as depiicted in the last figure in the image below ? Can anyone show why this is forming? FSSE here means Fraunhofer single slit experiment. [image]

Comment: This should help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-slit_experiment

Comment: I was asking of the pattern in the last figure i know about the normal YDSE setup that is figure 1

Comment: The reason I put the wiki link was the final equation in the "Classical wave-optics formulation" section of the link. If you plot it, you'll get the final figure you've been showing and then you can read the explanation for it.

Comment: Maybe it would be better to prove that formula from basics ((i.e. intensity pattern in case of double slits separated by d and the wavelength(lambda) is comparable to the two slits width a )) as a answer to this post.

Comment: I would be happy to do that but right now I'm looking for a very well-written related post on stackexchange which already had what you are asking for. I want to avoid duplicates.

Comment: Yeah sure Sir that would also be good for me :)

Comment: http://web.mit.edu/viz/EM/visualizations/coursenotes/modules/guide14.pdf includes the calculations and I took it from a comment on this post: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/382799/youngs-double-split-experiment-the-slit-width/382815#382815

Comment: Wonderful Sir , just one thing which i didnt get in that why they said Intensity will be just multiplication of both independent intensity patterns , they didnt mention a proof or a reason as why in 14.7 . And is there some sort of criteria for this type of pattern to be shown ? Like it will not be possible to observe when rayleigh criteria or some stuff is not satisfied right ?

Comment: The Feynman path integral is another method.

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/659531/single-slit-diffraction-from-feynmans-rotating-amplitudes-little-arrows

Comment: @Newbie Sir may you respond to my query?

Comment: Thanks @PhysicsDave

Comment: No problem, the whole interference thing where 2 photons cancel is a bit old fashioned and of course is a violation of conservation of energy. Dirac, Feynman and many others realized each photon has a predetermined path .... most likely by virtual forces.